# Scrapy passed one page from parsing

Tags: scrapy, dokuwiki

Here is my spider, which I run from a script to parse content of my local dokuwiki:

```python
    DEBUG = True
    if DEBUG:
        f_debug = open('debug.log','w')

    md5s = []
    class DokuWikiMd5Spider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'dokuwikispider'
        start_urls = ['https://dokuwiki.mjcc.lasil.ru/doku.php']
        visited = []

        custom_settings = {
            'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1,
        }

        @staticmethod
        def get_page_name(url):
            url = url.replace("https://dokuwiki.mjcc.lasil.ru/doku.php?", '')
            if 'id=start&do=search' in url:
                # because credentials are in URL, here we cut only page name
                # https://dokuwiki.mjcc.lasil.ru/doku.php?id=start&do=search&id=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B&q=&p=PASSWORD&u=admin
                m = re.findall('id=([^&]+)', url)
                return m[1]
            else:
                m = re.search('id=([^&]+)', url)
                return m.group(1)

        def parse(self, response):
            password = keyring.get_password('dokuwiki', 'admin')
            return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
                response,
                formdata = {'u': 'admin', 'p': password},
                callback = self.after_login
            )

        def after_login(self, response):
            # check login succeed before going on
            if b"authentication failed" in response.body:
                self.logger.error("Login failed")
                return

            # continue scraping with authenticated session...
            if DEBUG:
                f_debug.write("parsing: {}\n".format(response.url))
            text = response.text
            # cut everything except page content, not to depend on wiki settings when comparing
            m = re.findall('.*(<!-- wikipage start -->.*<!-- wikipage stop -->).*', text, re.DOTALL)
            text = m[0][0]

            # with open(r'F:\TEMP\test.html','w') as f:
            #     f.write(text)
            md5 = hashlib.md5()


            md5.update(text.encode('utf-8'))


            md5s.append({'url': self.get_page_name(response.url), 'md5': md5.hexdigest()})
            yield {'url': self.get_page_name(response.url), 'md5': md5.hexdigest()}
            for next_page in response.xpath('//a/@href'):

                next_url = next_page.extract()
                if DEBUG:
                    f_debug.write("\t?next page: {}\n".format(next_url))

                if 'doku.php?id=' in next_url:
                    # to process every page name only one time
                    next_page_name = self.get_page_name(next_url)
                    if next_page_name not in self.visited:
                        if DEBUG:
                            f_debug.write("\t\t!\n")

                        self.visited.append(next_page_name)
                        yield response.follow("https://dokuwiki.mjcc.lasil.ru/{}&u=admin&p={}".format(next_url, keyring.get_password('dokuwiki', 'admin')), self.after_login)

    process = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
    })


    process.crawl(DokuWikiMd5Spider)
    process.start()  # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

So in debug messages I see, that spider crowled page 'wiki_backup':

```
2019-01-28 19:49:22 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://dokuwiki.mjcc.lasil.ru//doku.php?id=wiki_backup&u=admin&p=PASSWORD> (referer: https://dokuwiki.mjcc.lasil.ru//doku.php?id=%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B1%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2&u=admin&p=PASSWORD)
```

And I can see its content in the crawled method, as you can see in screenshot [image: pycharm debug]

But that page wasn't parsed even one time, as you can see in ''debug.log'':

```
root@F91_Moin20:/home/ishayahu # cat debug.log | grep wiki_backup
        ?next page: /doku.php?id=wiki_backup
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in a way, how spider checks if authentification was failed. It (as in the tutorial) search for words "authentification failed", but because I had the same words in page content, spider thought that here was an authentification error and stop processing the page.
There should be another way to check if authentification was really failed.

Comment: The [Scrapy tutorial](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) does not cover authentication at all, what tutorial are you talking about? As for “There should be another way to check if authentification was really failed”, there is, you can check so however you want. Adapt your code to the target website accordingly.

Comment: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.5/topics/request-response.html#using-formrequest-from-response-to-simulate-a-user-login

Comment: You are right. I’ll suggest a modification upstream to try to avoid confusion.